# Spring JDBCTemplate + Transaction Manager memory leak

Tags: java, mysql, spring, memory-leaks

i have really strange problem. My Spring web-application seems to have a memory-leak.
i'm using Spring 3.2

my Tomcat config:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
-XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/dumps"
```

my dataSource declaration:

```
<!-- declare transactionManager -->
<tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<beans:bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="dataSource"  
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">  
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />  
    <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test" />  
    <beans:property name="username" value="User" />  
    <beans:property name="password" value="password" />
    <beans:property name="initialSize" value="5" />
    <beans:property name="maxActive" value="55" />
    <beans:property name="maxIdle" value="20" />
    <beans:property name="minIdle" value="10" />
    <beans:property name="maxWait" value="10000" />
    <beans:property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="55000" />
    <beans:property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="34000" />
    <beans:property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <beans:property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
    <beans:property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="60"/>
    <beans:property name="logAbandoned" value="true"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

i'm injecting the jdbcTemplate into dao. I'm using Transaction-Annotations as well.

this is what i got from Memory Analizer (MAT):

> The class "com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver", loaded by "org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader @ 0x515c1390", occupies 758.845.296 (72,57%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment[]" loaded by "system class loader".

in the detail-view i saw this:

> com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver$ConnectionPhantomReference
>   First 10 of 14.360 objects. Number of Objects: 14.360. Used Heap Size: 459.520. Retained Heap Size: 732.819.568

i found this: [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68400), but i'm using 5.1.29, so i think i shouldn't have this problem. But maybe the problem is somewhere in apache dbcp. Can someone help me? Is my configuration ok? Is there a problem in JDBCTemplate + TransactionManager?

here is 1 of my services. I use Transactions in the services, is it ok?

```
@Service
public class ModerationServiceImpl implements ModerationService {
    @Autowired
    private EventService eventService;

    @Autowired
    private ContentManagementService cmService;

    @Autowired
    private IconDao iconDao;

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    @Override
    public void activateUserIcon(long userIconId, long userId, String comment)
        throws IconNotFoundException, NoPermissionException, IOException,
        IconNotAssignedToUserException, WrongIconStateException {
    if(!iconDao.isAssignedToUser(userIconId))
        throw new IconNotAssignedToUserException("icon: " + userIconId + " is not assigned to a user and can't be activated!");
    cmService.activateUserIcon(userIconId);
    eventService.writeUserIconEvent(userIconId, userId, new Date().getTime(), Enum_ServerEvent.verified, Enum_UserIconState.approved, comment);
}
```

and here is 1 of my DAO's:

```
@Repository
public class IconDaoImpl extends DB_Contract implements IconDao{
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public IconData getUserIconById(long iconId) throws IconNotFoundException {
    String sql = SELECT + UserIcon.CN_ServerID + NEXT +
            UserIcon.CN_State + NEXT +
            UserIcon.CN_Ref + 
            FROM + UserIcon.TABLE_NAME + WHERE + UserIcon.CN_ServerID + " = ?";
    try{
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new UserIconRowMapper(), iconId);
    }catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e){
        throw new IconNotFoundException("couldn't find icon for id: " + iconId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code that is manifesting the memory leak? Can be a lot of things.

Comment: what kind of code? do you mean some DAO-code?

Comment: @M.Deinum i added service and dao example

Comment: @M.Deinum i actually don't know, what is the problem(thats why i'm asking), i only can see, that the JDBC-driver can not release the connections. I put a heap-dump into the MAT after an OutOfMemory-Exception and it showed me, that there are >700 mb `ConnectionPhantomReference's`

Comment: Nothing, at first sight, in your services or dao that is wrong. Have you tried a different connection pool like [HikariCP](http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/) or [C3P0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) just to rule out problems with DBCP.

Comment: i'm testing tomcat-jdbc right now, it will prob take about 1 day to get outOfMemory, I'll update, if i get the Problem. Thx for your help

Comment: @M.Deinum ok, after few days there is no OutOfMemory and GC seems to be able to free the memory, so i guess the problem was indeed dbcp. Can you recommend some connection pool?

Comment: I have good experiences with c3p0 but that is quite old. Nowadays I mostly use tomcat-jdbc (which should be default in tomcat 7 now). I tried HikariCP in a test project and seems fine too.